# Custom NavigationBar Buttons Look Different in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, user-interface

Building my app using the iOS 7 SDK changes the look of the navigation bar and its buttons:

[image: navbar comparison]

The top image shows what it looks like when run on a device using iOS 6, the bottom image shows the same app running on a device using iOS 7.

The navigation bar is created using a background image:

```
UIImage *navigationBarBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTopNavigationBackground"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 4, 0)];

UINavigationBar *bar = [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationController class], nil];
[bar setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.17 green:0.62 blue:0.23 alpha:1.0]];
```

The left bar button is created by:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)slideoverMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_icon_menu.png"]
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(slideoverMenu)];
}
```

I'm more concerned with what is happening to the button appearance. What are the "best practices" for handling this transition to the new iOS 7 look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Navigation bar background:**

You need to use a stretchable image to fill the navigation bar.  Because your image appears to be a fairly simple gradient, something like this should get you close:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[navigationBarBackgroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0]];
```

and your background image becomes a 1w x 64h png.

**Bar button image:**

use [UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]

```
 UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_button_icon_menu.png"];
 return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[buttonImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                           target:self
                                           action:@selector(slideoverMenu)];

}
```

as the default behavior is to paint your non-transparent image pixels with the application tint color, "always original" mode will prevent that from happening.

Comment: This works very well for iOS 7, but I must test this method's availablity (imageWithRenderingMode) when running under iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Since the status bar is now part of the navigation bar, your custom navigation bar background image should be able to stretch across the status bar and navigation bar, or should be high enough for both.

Answer (score 0):

the button is in the same place, but you navigation bar moves upwards. Probably try to block this attempt of "want full screen".

See in the project definition page General -> Deployment info -> Status bar style
or in code if you override it.

Besides, there's new in iOS property setSelectedImage, check it too